# keep ModalBottomSheet expanded compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet

I have the following code for my bottom sheet.

```
val skipPartiallyExpanded by remember {
    mutableStateOf(true)
}
val bottomSheetState =
    rememberModalBottomSheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded = skipPartiallyExpanded)

    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = {
            onDismissRequest()
            onSearchTextChange("")
        },
        sheetState = bottomSheetState,
    )
```

I want to keep the bottom sheet expanded at all time, but it gets smaller whenever the content gets smaller too.
I thought that setting `skipPartiallyExpanded` to true would do the trick, but it is not working as I would expect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solve the problem by making the content of the bottom sheet fill the max size.

```
modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
```

And of course `skipPartiallyExpanded` is always true

```
val bottomSheetState =
    rememberModalBottomSheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded = true)
```